# Easiest way to extend a form by a property?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I did a lot of searching but nothing really helped me... so here's the problem:
I need an additional Property like

```
public int FormResult()
{
   get{ ....
```

The thing is I'm calling the Forms via

```
Form f1 = new Forms.Form2();
f1.Show;
.....
```

So I cannot just put the property inside the form since I could only access it then if I used

```
 Form2 f1 = new Forms.Form2();
```

What I'd need is to extend the whole Form class by that property (or maybe u have a better idea..?) I first thought of the normal Class extension but that couldn't access the Resultvariable inside the class.
Then I thought I'd just create a new class inheriting from Form and add that property...as one would normally do. Then I'd just use that class on all my forms and it should work - but this is where VS tells me I have inconsistent access and that lets say clsExtForm is less accessable than Form2.

This looked like this:

```
class clsExtForm : Form
{
    private int result;
    Public int FormResult()
    {
       Get{ return result; }
       Set{ result = value; }
    }
}
```

Then I would have used

```
    ClsExtForm f1 = new Forms.Form2();
```

and changed Form2 to

```
    public partial class Form2 : clsExtForm
```

That gave the above error...

**Solved - all I was missing was "public" before "class clsExtForm" and they had the right accessability level....sorry...early in the morning here in Germany :)
Any reasons why this way of doing it shouldn't be ok?**

I'm looking forward to your answers! 
Thanks for any help!

Greetings,
Lorenz

Comment: Can you post the entire form sub-class?

Comment: What is `clsExtForm`? It's not really clear where you're getting an error, or exactly what you're actually doing. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Maybe you want to try using extension methods? 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: There's no reason whatsoever to not use Form2.  Use *var* instead if that makes you happier.  Naming an instance variable "f1" for a type named Form2, that's evil though.